# how to convert data from the database in json?

Tags: java, json, datatable, tomcat7, converters

i am using eclipse with tomcat v7. I need to display a datatable. The data are taken from mysql database. I am using java to retrive data from database. but i need to convert this data into json format. Datatable use only json data. so please help me to convert data into json format.

i need data in this format

```
String json = "{ \"aaData\":[[\"First Name1\",\"Last Name1\",\"Address1\",\"Address2\"],[\"First Name\",\"Last Name\",\"Address\",\"sdfsdf\"]]}";
```

Comment: Create a class with the structure you mentioned, populate the values and use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert that object to a json.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Json with Jakson library

[Check this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/)

```
ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();

String json = ow.writeValueAsString(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use JPA annotations to directly fetch data into a POJO
you can refer [this](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/retrieve) for the same

after fetching the same you can use JAXB or any other API to convert that into JSON directly
for JAXB you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357366/converting-java-object-to-json-using-marshaller) for json conversion

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
String json = "{ \"aaData\":[[\"First Name1\",\"Last Name1\",\"Address1\",\"Address2\"],[\"First Name\",\"Last Name\",\"Address\",\"sdfsdf\"]]}";

JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();

Object myJson = parser.parse(json);
```